# Split string containg dash/hyphen character in Java

Tags: java

I have a string

> May 1988 – June 1992

I want to split this string in such way that I will get two separate strings **May 1988** and **June 1992** .

I tried the following code:

```
String sample="May 1988 – June 1992";
String[] arr=sample.split(" - ");
```

Comment: And what's the problem with your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: When i print arr[0] ,the output is May 1988 – June 1992

Comment: Are you sure that is a space dash space between your dates? Might it be a double dash?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is space dash space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String you are trying to split has a "en dash" (U+2013), while you try to split with a "HYPHEN-MINUS" (U+002D).
Seeing the difference with your eyes is pretty hard (dash is slighly longer), but they are different symbols.

just copy and paste the en dash into your split method and it should work:

```
String[] arr=sample.split(" – ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is yours two dash are not the same :
 `-` is not  `–`